# Define vector length globaly in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to set globaly length of vector of data, which later goes into function() on numerous places, so I'm annoyed about retyping this on several places.

```
x[1:10]
```

How can I set `1:10` globaly so that I can re-use it in the above example as following:

```
global <- 1:10
x[glboal]
```

I have tried with `paste()` but cannot get it into simple numeric `1:10`. Please note I don't want `x <- 1:10` look like `[1]` `1 2 3 4 5 ....`

As soon as objection appear about this question (bad coding manner/question type etc.), I will erase this post asap.

EDIT:  I thought about it as: `cat(paste("1:10",sep=""),collapse="")`

Comment: Use a custom attribute?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean by that.

Comment: The problem, I think, in your code is that you try to subset a vector `x` with `[]` and to select a column (2) but since `x` is a vector, that doesnt work. If you had a data.frame `df`, then `df[x,2]` would work

Comment: I erased the column(2) since that's confusing. I'm really looking only for `1:10` so that I could define other `x[global]` as `x[1:10]`

Comment: I dont see the difference between `1:10` and `1,2,...,10`. In terms of subsetting it doesnt seem to make a difference as far as i can see

Comment: @cenka, no it doesn't work. Its same as `<-` (within RStudio).

Comment: I'm still unsure what you're trying to achieve... Do you mean `assign('global', 1:10, envir=globalenv())`?

Comment: I'm sorry my weak explanatory skill.I don't mean necessarily "globaly" but just to assign literaly `1:10` to some variable named `global` or if you like `y` so that by calling `y` I get only `1:10` and not `[1]` 1 2 3 4 5 6 ..

Comment: `1:10` is just a shorthand and basically the same as `1,2,...,10`. Check `all.equal(1:10, c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10))`. I dont think you can store this in a variable as numeric, since `:` is not numeric. so in any case, I believe you would have to do some kind of conversion before using it (but from my understanding there is no need for that). If this doesnt work for you, please give an example where it doesnt work, so that we can better understand what you are trying to do

Comment: @beginneR: I thought about it as: `cat(paste("1",":","10",sep="),collapse")` but would like to have it assigned to a variable rather than just printed on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what you are trying to do. Maybe this?

```
global <- substitute(x <- 1:10)
global
#x <- 1:10
eval(global)
x
#[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Or this?

```
global1 <- substitute(1:10)
global1
#1:10
eval(global1)
#[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Comment: Great! Yes, `substitute()` does what I need! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You said you need to pass a global variable to a function, so perhaps something like this?

```
> x <- quote(1:10)
> x
## 1:10
> f <- function() eval(get('x'))
> f()
## [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```